# Difficulty in building Dashboard Side Control Panel

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a side Control Panel for Dashboard something similar to http://demo.neontheme.com/dashboard/highlights/

Can anyone give me some pointers for some examples where I can start building it ?

Thanks

Comment: What are some things you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Bootstrap's vast range of Components (if you haven't already), and break down the functionality according to what you wish to accomplish.
For example, at a glance:

I can see that the page is fluid, and the left-hand navigation takes up roughly 2/12 (by default, Bootstrap utilises a 12-column grid system).

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <!-- Menu -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <!-- Content -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Accordions are in use to collapse/expand menu items, so you can harness Bootstrap's `collapse.js` to achieve this.
Also, some menu items have Labels and/or Badges attached to them, which Bootstrap also caters for.

**Resources:**

- http://www.getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-fluid
- http://www.getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse
- http://www.getbootstrap.com/components/#labels
- http://www.getbootstrap.com/components/#badges